# API for Data extension update in sfmc salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, dataextensions

I need to push some data on daily basis from ERP to SFMC

The package is already created on marketing cloud (read, write on Data extension).

I created a first POST request :

Body :

```
{ 
    "client_id": "client id of my package", 
    "client_secret": "client secret of my pakcage", 
    "account_id": "my accound id", 
    "grant_type": "client_credentials" 
}
```

URL : `https://my_subdomain.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token`

The second part is more confused for me. I created a second POST request :

URL : `https://my_subdomain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/async/dataevents/key:External_Key_Of_My_Data_Extension/rowset`

What i wrote in the body (raw & JSON):

```
Host: https://my_subdomain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/
POST /hub/v1/dataevents/key:External_Key_Of_My_Data_Extension/rowset
Content-Type: application/json
```

In the authorization tab, I selected Bearer token and pasted the token that i obtained in the first POST request.

When i send the request =>

```
{"documentation":"https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm","errorcode":0,"message":"Bad Request"}
```

Does someone know where is my mistake ?

EDIT:
Here my POST request

[image]

I had this message :
{"documentation":"https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm","errorcode":0,"message":"Not Authorized"}

DOes someone know what does this mean ?

Answer (score 0):

To insert Data Extension, you would need to use the REST API endpoint from this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/insertDataExtensionIDAsync.html)

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /data/v1/async/dataextensions/key:{{Your DE customer Key}}/rows
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Sample Body:

```
{
   "items": [{
      "FirstName":"Bobby",
      "LastName" : "Jones",
      "ZipCode": "23456"
   },
   {
      "FirstName":"Sam",
      "LastName" : "Sneed",
      "ZipCode": "23456"
   }]
}
```

In case you want to upsert a DE, then refer to this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/updateDataExtensionIDAsync.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case, I want to send data from a source A to a source B (my data extension). The source A is the data coming from the ERP and that will go to my DE on daily basis. I tried your method, i had error message (I edited my post to share what I wrote in the request). Sorry if it seems that my mistake is a stupid one, I'm completely a beginner in api call

Comment: @ayakuza91 you might want to call the authentication request again to get a new access token then use it to retry with the 2nd call to insert the record to the DE. Since an access token v2 life time is 20 minutes.

Comment: Yes exactly, I managed to insert a record when i refresh the token and write a sample body but I don't know what looks like the data which is going to be pushed to me from ERP to my data extension so I don't know what I have to write in the body. How to parameter this ?

Comment: @ayakuza91 I don't quite understand your question.. You are supposed to be the one who configures which value will be used in the body. For example, in the "items" array, you can specify `"items": [{"Your field DE name 1" : "Your ERB value 1", "Your field DE name 2" : "Your ERB value 2"}, so on....]`

Comment: ok I understand what you mean and it seems that I didn't really understand how does api call work. So, if the data that I want to push from ERP to a SFMC data extension contains 400 records (2 columns, 400 rows), should I have to 400 times like "items": [{"Your field DE name 1" : "Your ERB value 1", "Your ERB value 2", ... "Your ERB value 400","Your field DE name 2" : "Your ERB value 1","Your ERB value 2",..."Your ERB value 400"}

Comment: @ayakuza91 If it has 400 records with 2 columns, then it will be `"items": [{"Your field DE name 1" : "Your ERB value 1", "Your field DE name 2" : "Your ERB value 2"}, {...}]` The items array will have 400 {...} items, each {...} is 1 row in the DE. The body will need to be adjusted based on your daily data and based on how you process it